# KnockoutJS - which runs first, extenders or subscriptions (manually set up or otherwise) and what about if they're overwritten?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

This seems like a fairly simple question but I can't find much of an answer or explanation anywhere without contradictions. See the class below;

```
export class Person {
    FirstName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    Surname: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    FullName: KnockoutComputed<string>;
    SurnameExternalReference: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor(data) {
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name).extend(someExtender: logChange);
        this.Surname = ko.observable(data.SurnameName).extend(someExtender: logChange);
        this.FullName = ko.copmuted(() => {
            return this.FirstName() + " " + this.Surname();
        }, this);
        this.SurnameExternalReference = ko.observable();

        this.Surname.subscribe(() => {
             //function here tests an external ko array of people for that surname 
             //and assigns this.SurnameExternalReference to that observable.
             //e.g.  - then sets sub back up as below only if found, otherwise this.SurnameExternalReference = null
             this.SurnameExternalReference = external.Surname;
             this.SurnameExternalReference.subscribe(() => {
                 this.Surname(this.SurnameExternalReference());
                 });

            });

        this.SurnameExternalReference.subscribe(() => {
            this.Surname(this.SurnameExternalReference());
        });
    }
}
```

I've written this for reference only, my actual viewModel is extremely complex and impossible to post, but it does (and needs to do) this. logChange is a function that tests the input and logs the change if it's valid otherwise doesn't write the new value (or log change).

So my question is, if the external surname property is changed, in what order would the extenders and functions be called? Bearing in mind that in the surname subscription this.SurnameExternalReference inherits external.surname's extender.

Are extenders always called before subscriptions? Are subscriptions called in order they're set (I've found many people agreeing on the order being fairly random AND in the order they're set up)?

If the observable is externally overwritten does it inherit the order of the external sub/extender or get added to the end?

Pretty complicated question, ask any questions/post scenarios if confused.

EDIT: is it possible for extenders/subscriptions to be running asynchronously or can they only run synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pretty complicated question

Agreed. Partly because your code example does some things it probably shouldn't.

> Are subscriptions called in order they're set

Yes.

> Are extenders always called before subscriptions

An extender always has the first opportunity to "do something" with a newly created observable. E.g:

```
ko.extenders.logChange = function(obs, log) {
    if (log) obs.subscribe(console.log); // 1
    return obs;
};

const myName = ko.observable("Jane").extend({ logChange: true });
myName.subscribe(console.log); // 2
```

The subscription created by the extender is attached first, and will do the first log. Of course, you can do all kinds of weird things in the extender function, which means there's never a guarantee. This contrived example swaps the order of the logs:

```
ko.extenders.logChange = function(obs, log) {
    if (log) setTimeout(() => obs.subscribe(console.log)); // 2
    return obs;
};

const myName = ko.observable("Jane").extend({ logChange: true });
myName.subscribe(console.log); // 1
```

For your specific more complicated case, I'd advise you to put some breakpoints in the code and update the observable to study the order in which dependencies are evaluated.

If this doesn't help you solve your real problem, you might want to provide a runnable example of the logic you're trying to implement.

Note: when creating subcriptions *inside* another subscription, it's best to dispose the earlier created ones to prevent weird behavior.